# Qlikview folder list using QMS api

Tags: qlikview

I am able successfully  to get the list of qlikview files using the following code with QMS api.

```
    string key = Client.GetTimeLimitedServiceKey();
    ServiceKeyClientMessageInspector.ServiceKey = key;
    ServiceInfo[] qvService = Client.GetServices(ServiceTypes.QlikViewServer);
    DocumentNode[] allDocs = Client.GetUserDocuments(qvService[0].ID);
```

But now this simply lists the qlikview files. What about the folders? Can someone kindly suggest me the code to get the folders as well?

[image: QlikView Folders]

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample in the QMS API Documentation under the `GetSourceDocumentFolders` method. The example writes the name of all documents and folders to the console by using recursion to navigate through sub folders.

This is not exactly what you need, but you can adapt this to store these in an array, etc. I have attempted to change the variable names to match your code you already supplied:

```
List<DocumentFolder> sourceDocumentsFolders = Client.GetSourceDocumentFolders(qvService[0].ID, DocumentFolderScope.General | DocumentFolderScope.Services);
foreach (DocumentFolder sourceDocumentFolder in sourceDocumentsFolders.OrderBy(x => x.General.Path)) {
    // print the names of all source document folders, prefix with [R] for root folders
    Console.WriteLine("[R] " + sourceDocumentFolder.General.Path);

    // print all sub nodes of the current source document folder
    PrintSourceDocumentNodes(Client, sourceDocumentFolder, string.Empty, 1);
}

static void PrintSourceDocumentNodes(IQMS apiClient, DocumentFolder sourceDocumentFolder, string relativePath, int indentationDepth) {
    // retrieve all source document nodes of the given folder and under the specified relative path
        List<DocumentNode> sourceDocumentNodes = apiClient.GetSourceDocumentNodes(sourceDocumentFolder.Services.QDSID, sourceDocumentFolder.ID, relativePath);
    foreach (DocumentNode sourceDocumentNode in sourceDocumentNodes.OrderByDescending(x => x.IsSubFolder).ThenBy(x => x.Name)) {
        // print the names of all source document nodes, indent and prefix with [F] for folders and [D] for documents
        string indentation = new string(' ', indentationDepth * 3);
        string nodePrefix = (sourceDocumentNode.IsSubFolder ? "[F]" : "[D]");
        Console.WriteLine(indentation + nodePrefix + " " + sourceDocumentNode.Name);
        // print all sub nodes of the current source document node if it represents a folder
        if (sourceDocumentNode.IsSubFolder) {
            PrintSourceDocumentNodes(apiClient, sourceDocumentFolder, relativePath + "\\" + sourceDocumentNode.Name, indentationDepth + 1);
                }
        }
}
```